# viewDidLoad not getting called for item on UITabViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

on a button click ,via segue the flow goes to UITabViewController.

```
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.gotoResult, sender: nil)
   let myUrl = NSURL(string: "XXXXXXXX");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
        // Compose a query string

        resultVar.city = cityText.text
        resultVar.state = streetText.text

        let postString = "streetaddr=\(streetText.text)&city=\(cityText.text)&state=\(stateVal)&degree=\(degreeVal)";

        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error= \(error)")
                return
            }
            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

            // Print out response body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")


            do {
                    resultVar.myJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                } catch let error2 as NSError? {
                        print("error 2 \(error2)")
            }

        }

            task.resume()
```

There is a UITabViewController with three items. when the initial view gets loaded(item1) the viewDidLoad is not getting called. for now I have added the same code in viewDidAppear and when i click on a different tab and come back to item1 ,the fields are populated. But I want it to work on initial load after the segue only. What am I missing?

ViewdidLoad of Item1

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        print("in here CityViewController")

        if let parseJSON = resultVar.myJSON {
            // Now we can access value of elements by its key
            var weather_condition = parseJSON["weather_condition"] as! String
            print("weather_condition: \(weather_condition)")

            weatherconditionLbl.text = weather_condition
        }
```

The code which gets called when i switch tabs:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        print("in here CityViewController1")

        if let parseJSON = resultVar.myJSON {
            // Now we can access value of elements by its key
            var weather_condition = parseJSON["weather_condition"] as! String
            print("weather_condition: \(weather_condition)")


            weatherconditionLbl.text = weather_condition + "in " + resultVar.city+","+resultVar.state


        }

    }
```

so the code viewdidload is not getting called and viewDidAppear gets called when i switch tabs.

Comment: Did you try by checking break point it may called same time as you clicked button.

Comment: Try adding a break point at   print("in here CityViewController") in viewDidLoad.

Comment: i think use self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.gotoResult, sender: nil) after network response came.

Comment: when i ran in debug mode, it is printing "in here CityViewController" and then  it is skipping  in condition "if let parseJSON = resultVar.myJSON" . am checking why.

Comment: Thought so, viewDidLoad is working as you would expect but your resultVar.myJSON is nil.  Look at doing the segue after the data is returned.

Answer (score 0):

A network request will be slower than rendering the next scene so "parseJSON" is not there.  You need to refresh your graphics using a callback from the network request.  In order to do that I suggest that you call the network request from "Item 1" every time you need to refresh its content (that is up to you).